# .net Libraries not showing on Mac OSX El Capital 10.11.6

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have Visual Studio Community for Mac v7.33 installed so I can create a C# application. Using Homebrew I installed openssl 1.0.2. I also installed .net Core SDK 1.1.7 (x64) for Mac, yet I cannot access the System.Windows.Forms library to create a simple button. What am I missing here? How do I access the standard .net libraries or is it a different process for a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no .net core version of windows.forms.   The closest you will find to windows forms on a mac is to create a new project and look under other --> .net --> Gtk# 2.0 project

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this now.

Comment: Can you connect to SQL using GTK#? I can only find the .NET version, System.data.SQL.